# Issue with correct results when using a stored procedure vs a query statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this web app where a user enters data in a webform using a checkboxlist and a text box to enter a value and date. Those values entered are then updated to a database using a stored procedure.

When using a stored procedure, the webapp works correctly, but if I use an `Update` statement instead, it updates the database with the values entered by the user times the number of items selected in the database.

For example if there are 11 items in the checkboxlist with all items checked, with the stored procedure, if a user enters 12, each value in the database will be 12, but using the update statement, each value entered will be 132, can anyone explain to me why it does that and if there is a way to get the same results as the stored procedure?

```
CREATE TABLE AccountTable
(
    RowID int IDENTITY(1, 1),
    AccountID varchar(2),
    AccountName varchar(50),
    SeqNum int,
    SeqDate datetime
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [ACCOUNTTABLE_UPDATE]
    (@SeqNum int,
     @SeqDate datetime,
     @Account_ID varchar(2)
    )
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN
        UPDATE AccountTable
        SET SeqNum = SeqNum + @SeqNum, SeqDate =  @SeqDate
        WHERE AccountID = @AccountID
   END
```

C# code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime.TryParseExact(datepicker.Text, "mmddyyyy", provider, style out dt);

int i = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
//DropDownList Binded from database values in another method

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnString());

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[Table_Update]";

//Update Query cmd.CommandText = "Update Account Table SET SeqNum = SeqNum + @SeqNum, SeqDate = @SeqDate WHERE AccountID = @AccountID;";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeqNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = i
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeqDate",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
cmd.Parameters["@Account_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue;

foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList.Items)
{
     if (item.Selected)
     {
         cmd.Parameters["@SeqNum"].Value = i;
         cmd.Parameters["@SeqDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;
         cmd.Parameters["@Account_ID"].Value = item.Value;

          try
          {
             con.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
          catch (SqlException ex)
          {
              Response.Write(ex.Message);
              //Database Exceptions
          }
          finally
          {
              con.Close();
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: In the Update query, if there is already a value in the database, it adds the number entered by the user plus what's already in the table set for the specific "Account_ID" selected.

Comment: You are defining your parameters twice - why is that? Is there any code you are not showing us where `i` is being manipulated?

Comment: @user1666620 Or `DateTime.Now` for that matter.

Comment: Probably a good idea to move your loop inside the con.Open/con.Close statements so you only use one connection, as well. Move you com inside the loop and your con outside the loop. That way you're not adding to the same com but creating a new one each time

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 public void data2()
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(datepicker.Text, "mmddyyyy", provider, style out dt);

        int i = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
        int check = 0;
        //DropDownList Binded from database values in another method

        foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {

                check++;
            }
        }
        using (SqlConnection conn = GetConnString())
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                //    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[Table_Update]";
                cmd.CommandText = "Update Account Table SET SeqNum = SeqNum + @SeqNum, SeqDate = @SeqDate WHERE AccountID = @AccountID";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeqNum", check);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeqDate", DateTime.Now);
                cmd.Parameters["@Account_ID", CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

or, it TextBox1.Text is already the number you want to save...

```
    public void data3()
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(datepicker.Text, "mmddyyyy", provider, style out dt);

        int i = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
                    //DropDownList Binded from database values in another method

        using (SqlConnection conn = GetConnString())
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                //    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[Table_Update]";
                cmd.CommandText = "Update Account Table SET SeqNum = SeqNum + @SeqNum, SeqDate = @SeqDate WHERE AccountID = @AccountID";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeqNum", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeqDate", DateTime.Now);
                cmd.Parameters["@Account_ID", CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

**NOTE** that in both cases, because your SQL contains "SeqNum = SeqNum + @SeqNum", it will save a running total of how many pictures, adding those selected here to any selected before. If you don't want to do that, modify your SQL to "SeqNum = @seqNum" and it will modify to the number selected only during this page load.

Comment: Thanks Shannon, the Stored Procedure works fine, but if I use a an Update Query which is the same statement in the stored procedure, I get the wrong results.

Comment: even if this does work, it's a bad answer as it doesn't explain what the error is or how the code you've provided is better.

Comment: I described that in my comment above. "Move your conn out of the loop and move your com inside the loop so you aren't adding to the same com over and over again but creating a new one"

Comment: I apologize, I did read that, will let you know the results when I perform changes.

Comment: No worries - btw, I forgot to move the foreach loop inside the conn.Open() - it'll work as I originally typed, but the edit should be better. This assumes that there will always be at least one checkbox cheked. If it'll sometimes be empty, you may want to alter the logic so it doesn't go through and open/close a connection unnecessarily.

Comment: all right I tried that and the Update Query still does the same thing enters in values multiplying by the amount entered by the user. If I use a stored procedure, it adds them just fine, I don't understand why they would be producing different results if essentially, it's the same thing.

Comment: well, I tweaked it a bit and it's working fine, updates the database just fine, but will throw errors stating that Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure. I don't know if clearing my parameters would be right here, but, it works as intended.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger you should probably place your original comment into the question in order to have a single, self-contained full answer, rather than hunting through comments to find the full answer.

Comment: Note that the SQL is different in your stored procedure and your statement as well.. in your statement it's seqNum = seqNum and seqDate+seqDate (which will add the two) and in your SP, it's SeqNum+SeqNum (which will add the two) and seqDate.

Comment: yes that's a typo in the question, I'll fix that. But in my code it's written correctly.

Comment: Please try the edited method above (comment out the stored procedure and use com.CommandText instead) and see if you get different results?

Comment: If I clear the parameters, using the update query it will perform incorrectly, but updating the database as it did with my initial issue, if I don't clear them it works correctly, but throws the exceptions.

Comment: I get the same results if I try the edited method above.

Comment: You mean you get bad results whether you run the first method I sent you or the modified one? Or do you mean that the results are still different?

Comment: I get bad results with the modified method you provided

Comment: Ok - that tells us something. Let's step back for a minute. What is it you're trying to do? There is a problem with the input data or the SQL somewhere. What are your checkboxes, what is your textbox, and why are you saving it to the DB?

Comment: the checkboxes are nicknames if you may, they are databound so they are pulled from the same database, my textbox is amount, I want to dynamically generate an image, the amount entered is the number of images, if there are 5 boxes checked and I want 4 images, if I execute my code using the Update Query statement, instead of updating the database that 4 images were entered, it updates with the value 20. Executing with the stored procedure in my code does not give that issue.

Comment: Ok - I got you. So Textbox1.Text would be the number of pics required? Because my code would ad that to itself for each checkbox checked. Let's try this a different way

Comment: Note that the revised methods above will still add the number of checkboxes to itself - such that if four boxes are checked (or TextBox1.Text = 4) then the database will update with the old value plus four. If you don't want that running total take out the +seqNum from your SQL

Comment: Is there a reason why it works perfectly with the stored procedure and if I just use the update query it does not work correctly?

Comment: It's not working differently. We just tested it using the same logic and got the same (bad) results. So there is something wrong and different between the two. Otherwise, you would get different results using the method I first sent versus the method I sent last.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger I want to thank you for all your help and everything. It was absolutely strange as to why it wasn't working, I read through my code and found a simple mistake that leaves me too embarrassed to explain on here. Again, I do want to sincerely thank you on taking the time to help me. My code kept executing as if always no matter what all boxes were selected, but I figured out the issue where it does work as intended.

Comment: Cool! I knew it was something in the way it was being fed. Glad you found it - that's what the goal was anyway. We've all been there! I'd appreciate you selecting my answer if you feel I've been helpful. Take care!